# Способ получения cookie C#

Tags: c#, парсер, cookie, авторизация, аутентификация

Каков принцип получения куки для их дальнейшего использования? Сейчас использую для этого webbrowser и уже куки оттуда вставляю в запрос, но хотелось бы найти более рациональный способ.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://kinopoisk.ru/s/type/all/find/"+"Хардкор");
        request.Referer = "https://www.kinopoisk.ru/";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586";
        request.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, webBrowser1.Document.Cookie);

        var responseToString = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)).ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое - это использовать `System.Net.CookieContainer`

Пример:

```
System.Net.CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
... // do something with request
var response = request.GetResponse();
... // do something with response
```

После выполнения запроса куки будут в `cookies`, их можно будет использовать в следующем запросе, `requestNext.CookieContainer = cookies`

Пример и описание можно еще [здесь посмотреть](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

Можно вручную в ответе от сервера парсить заголовки `Set-Cookie`. Пример как это делать есть [здесь](http://snipplr.com/view/4427/)

Comment: Пример кода, что привели здесь, он разве в переменную cookies что либо запишет?

Comment: @Андрей Федоров, поправил немного, предполагалось что в `... // do something` будет выполнен запрос к сайту `request.GetResponse();`, после этого в cookies будут записаны куки из Set-Cookie заголовка ответа, и их можно дальше использовать

Comment: @Андрей Федоров, да единственное были проблемы с контейнером в .NET 4, на одном сайте никак не хотел некоторые куки брать, на .NET 4.5 все хорошо было, но надо было на XP запускать, тогда пришлось делать по второму способу самому